# viewflipper only next animation

Tags: android, animation, viewflipper

I have created a viewflipper in order to flip between 2 views in android.

The problem is that I want to flip between these 2 views **using the same animation** (slide in). 
It works when i flip from view 1 -> view 2 but it uses the reverse animation when I'm flipping from view 2 -> view 1

Same thing happens when I use 3 views, everything is ok when flipping 1->2->3 but it uses the reverse animation during 3->1

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do like this you will be in full control of the animations and page flipping:

```
//ViewFlipper
ViewFlipper flipper;
//Four different animations
Animation OutToRight;
Animation OutToLeft;
Animation InFromRight;
Animation InFromLeft;        

OutToRight = new TranslateAnimation(
              Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,      Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f,
              Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
            );
OutToRight.setDuration(500);
        OutToRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

        OutToLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
              Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f,
              Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
            );
      OutToLeft.setDuration(500);
    OutToLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

    InFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
              Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f,
              Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
            );
    InFromRight.setDuration(500);
      InFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

    InFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
                  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
                  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
                );
    InFromLeft.setDuration(500);
    InFromLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

    //Animating Left to page 1

    flipper.setInAnimation(InFromLeft);
    flipper.setOutAnimation(OutToRight);
    flipper.setDisplayedChild(1);

    //Animating right to page 2
    flipper.setInAnimation(InFromRight);
    flipper.setOutAnimation(OutToLeft);
    flipper.setDisplayedChild(2);
```

Comment: In that case, set flipper.setInAnimation(InFromRight);
    flipper.setOutAnimation(OutToLeft);  and don't change them. These animations will then be used for any subsequent setDisplayedChild call